# Numbers with certain digits

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a certain exercise I am asked to find how many numbers with $6$ digits are there that use digits in the set $\{1\dots 8\}$ so that only and excatly a digit is repeated twice. Here is my reasoning:

One chooses which digit is repeated twice ($8$ options), and this pair can be located in $5$ positions. We have until now $8\cdot 5$.

Now begins the most interesting part. The text says that only a digit is repeated twice, but there is no restriction whether a digit can be repeated three times, four or whether there are no repetitions. Therefore, I have separated it in cases:

1. If no digit is repeated, it is easy: there are $8\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4$ options.
2. If a digit is repeated three times, there are $7$ possible digits that can be repeated, and $4$ positions in which that threesome can be placed. For the other number there are still $6$ possibilities, and therefore we have here $8\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 4\cdot 6$.
3. If a digit is repeated four times, there are $7$ possibilities of choosing which digit. Therefore here we have $8\cdot 5\cdot 7$.

   The total would be the sum of the number displayed at the end of each option. Is this right?

Comment: Must the repeating digits be adjacent to one another? You seem to imply this in your $8\cdot 5$.

Comment: I have just realised that not. Therefore, my reasoning is not correct. Instead of putting $8 \cdot 5$, I should have put $8\cdot {6\choose 2}$ I think

Comment: There are only ~1M possibilities here, so if you can code, you can do a brute-force count to check for yourself. I highly recommend doing this check yourself unless you feel pretty confident in your answer.

Comment: You also need to count for the permutation of the remaining non-repeating digits, so it should be $({6\choose 2} \cdot 8 )\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4$.

Comment: Why should I use a permutation here? Choosing $7$ elements doesn't require permutations, right?

Comment: Because, for example, $112345\neq 113245$. After you have chosen the two positions of the repeating digit, you have to choose 4 digits out of the remaining 7 digits, and choose how to arrange them to produce the final number.

Comment: I still do not get it, I mean, instead of putting $8 \cdot {6 \choose 2}$, should I put your product? Could you give me a complete answer?

Comment: ${6\choose 2}$ is only the number of positions the repeating digit can be placed. After placing the repeating digit, you are not done producing the final number. For example, let's say you choose $7$ as the repeating digit. Then you put it in position 1 and 2. I only know that the final number you will produce looks like $77XXXX$, but I still do not know which number you will produce. You still need to choose the digits to put in positions 3 to 6.

Comment: So, there wouldn't be any neccesity of distinguishing between three cases? Take into account that in my exercise, the requirement is that only a digit can be repeated twice, but that doesn't imply that it cannot be a digit which is repeated three times, or even four times

Comment: My comments above only address the case of "exactly 2 repeats." For the case of "at least 2 repeats," it can be calculated as $8^6-6!\cdot{8\choose 6}$, which is the number of all possible 6-digit numbers formed by $\{1,\dots,8\}$ minus the number of 6-digit numbers formed by $\{1,\dots,8\}$ without any repeating digits.

Comment: I understand what you say, but, isn't that only in the case where all the others must be different?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "all the others must be different." Any number that is not a number without repeats is a number with at least 2 repeats. Any number with at least 2 repeats is a number not without repeats. My approach is just "all numbers minus no repeats."

Comment: **To the original poster:** I can't add any analysis; the necessary analysis has already been given in the comments.  However, I surmise that you are still legitimately confused by the analysis that you have been given.  Fair enough.  In my opinion, the way for you to resolve your confusion is my manual effort.  That is, start with the elements of the set $~A =~\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}.~$ Assume that the problem requires that you use one of the elements in $~A~$ exactly twice, and that you select $~(k-2)~$ other elements in $~A~$ and use each of these elements exactly once each. ...see next comment

Comment: **To the original poster:** This means that you are trying to enumerate all of the ways of forming a $~k$-digit number.  For $~k \in \{3,4,5\},~$ let $~f(k)~$ denote the number of different satisfying $~k$-digit numbers.  **Manually** compute $~f(3).~$ Then, use this (somewhat emotional) experience to expand your intuition.  Then, manually compute $~f(4),~$ and then $~f(5).~$ Try to be sure that your $~f(3), ~f(4), ~$ and $~f(5)~$ computations are accurate.  Then, assuming that your intuition has been expanded, try to compute $~f(8).~$   ...see next comment

Comment: **To the original poster:** Then, compare your results with the analysis previously given in the comments.

Comment: Thanks four your approach, I'll see it like that